# BlobstoreService.createUploadUrl() throws NullPointerException

Tags: clojure, google-app-engine

On a local Google App Engine development server, I am getting a `NullPointerException` when calling `BlobstoreService.createUploadUrl()`:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.LocalBlobstoreService.getCurrentInstancePort(LocalBlobstoreService.java:257)
        at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.LocalBlobstoreService.createUploadURL(LocalBlobstoreService.java:139)
... [redacted]
```

As you can see from the stack trace the program throws within a `LocalBlobstoreService.getCurrentInstancePort()` call from the `com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev` namespace. Interestingly, I couldn't find the `com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev` namespace's source code. It doesn't seem to be on the https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine repository. I am using the procedures below to initialize an environment where I can run GAE services locally. The code is in Clojure, I tried keeping it tidy and expressive, I hope you won't have trouble understanding it.

I have spent the whole evening searching and trying to understand why this happens, but I've got nothing. Assistance would be much appreciated.

```
(ns local-gae
  "Tools for local development."
  (:import
    [java.io File]
    [java.util HashMap]
    [com.google.apphosting.api ApiProxy ApiProxy$Environment]
    [com.google.appengine.tools.development
    ApiProxyLocalFactory
    LocalServerEnvironment]))

(def port 8181)

(defn- set-app-engine-environment []
  "Sets up the App Engine environment for the current thread."
  (let [att (HashMap. {"com.google.appengine.server_url_key"
                      (str "http://localhost:" port)})
        env-proxy (proxy [ApiProxy$Environment] []
                    (isLoggedIn [] false)
                    (isAdmin [] false)
                    (getAuthDomain [] "")
                    (getRequestNamespace [] "")
                    (getDefaultNamespace [] "")
                    (getAttributes [] att)
                    (getAppId [] "_local_"))]
    (ApiProxy/setEnvironmentForCurrentThread env-proxy)))

(defn- set-app-engine-delegate [dir]
  "Initializes the App Engine services. Needs to be run (at least) per JVM."
  (let [local-env (proxy [LocalServerEnvironment] []
                    (getAppDir [] (File. dir))
                    (getAddress [] "localhost")
                    (getHostName [] "localhost")
                    (getPort [] port)
                    (waitForServerToStart [] nil)
                    (enforceApiDeadlines [] true)
                    (simulateProductionLatencies [] true))
        api-proxy (.create (ApiProxyLocalFactory.) local-env)]
    (ApiProxy/setDelegate api-proxy)))

(defn init-app-engine
  "Initializes the App Engine services and sets up the environment.
   To be called from the REPL."
  ([] (init-app-engine "/tmp"))
  ([dir]
  (set-app-engine-delegate dir)
  (set-app-engine-environment)))
```

This is the REPL session that illustrates the call:

```
user=> (require 'local-gae)
nil
user=> (import com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.BlobstoreServiceFactory)
com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.BlobstoreServiceFactory
user=> (local-gae/init-app-engine)
nil
user=> (.createUploadUrl (BlobstoreServiceFactory/getBlobstoreService) "/url")

NullPointerException   com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.LocalBlobstoreService.getCurrentInstancePort (LocalBlobstoreService.java:257)
```

Google App Engine Java SDK 1.9.17

Comment: Can you provide a link to the source code for the `LocalBlobstoreService` class?

Comment: @juan.facorro Interestingly, I couldn't find the `com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev` namespace's source code. It doesn't seem to be on the [https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine) repository. I don't know what to make of it.

Comment: I found the same thing when I looked for it so I assumed that you had implemented the class yourself :P. Version 1.9.17 has been released just a few days ago ([2014-12-08](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/downloads)) and the repository https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine is a mirror so it doesn't seem to have up-to-date code. I would test with a previous version of the SDK just in case this is a bug introduced in the latest version.

Comment: @juan.facorro I have found that .createUploadUrl() works fine in the DevServer, it must be something about this environment I use. I will try an older version this afternoon.

Comment: @juan.facorro I'm happy to say, that I have found that the feature/bug in question is only present starting with version 1.8.4 inclusive. So for the time being I'm reverting to 1.8.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that the feature/bug in question is only present starting with version 1.8.4 inclusive. So for the time being I'm reverting to 1.8.3.

By the way, I have opened an issue [here](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=11529).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I fixed it by deleting the local_db.bin file and all local blob keys in appengine-generated folder of my project.